# Aria tags and table filters

Tags: html, wai-aria

I have a HTML table with data. I've used a javascript library to add filters to the top of each column. I've been asked to make the application work with screen readers etc.

I'm using "Accessibility Insights" plug in to check the application. Its flagged up the table with "aria-requires-children".

The code is :

```
<thead>
  <tr role="row" class="...">        
    <th class=".." tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" unselectable="on" aria-sort="none" aria-label="...">
      <div class="">col 1</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr role="search" class="...">
    <td data-column="0">
      <input type="search" placeholder="" class="..." data-column="0" aria-label="...">
     </td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

I found that changing the second row to have a role of "row" instead of "search" removes the alert. Is that the correct approach or what can I change to make this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using semantic html elements such as <tr> and <th>, you should **not** specify a `role`, especially if you're specifying a role different from the default role.

See the "[Second rule of ARIA use](https://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#secondrule)":

> Do not change native semantics, unless you really have to.

The default role for a <tr> is `row`.  See https://w3c.github.io/html-aria/#el-tr. By changing it to `search`, you are essentially saying the <tr> is no longer a table row.  It's a [search area](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#search), which is a landmark role.

Then, once the <tr> is no longer a row, now you have an invalid table because direct children of a <table> must be a:

- <caption>
- <colgroup>
- <thead>
- <tbody>
- <tfoot>
- <tr>

Easy to fix by removing the superfluous roles, which aren't needed anyway.

```
<thead>
  <tr class="...">        
    <th class=".." tabindex="0" scope="col" aria-disabled="false" aria-sort="none" aria-label="...">
      <div class="">col 1</div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="...">
    <td data-column="0">
      <input type="search" placeholder="" class="..." data-column="0" aria-label="...">
     </td>
  </tr>
</thead>
```